# UWP ObservableCollection DependencyProperty

Tags: uwp, dependency-properties

I have a UWP `UserControl` with the following `DependencyProperty` defined:

```
public sealed partial class ToolBarModule : UserControl {

    public ToolBarModule() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.PrimaryCommands = new ObservableCollection<TileBarButton>();
    }

    public static DependencyProperty PrimaryCommandsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "PrimaryCommands", typeof(ObservableCollection<TileBarButton>), typeof(ToolBarModule),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ObservableCollection<TileBarButton> PrimaryCommands {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<TileBarButton>)GetValue(PrimaryCommandsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PrimaryCommandsProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

When trying to use this control like so:

```
<vcm:ToolBarModule x:Name="ToolBar">
    <vcm:ToolBarModule.PrimaryCommands>
        <vcm:TileBarButton Text="Hello World" />
    </vcm:ToolBarModule.PrimaryCommands>
</vcm:ToolBarModule>
```

I receive a design time error ``` Failed to add TileBarButton to ObservableCollection``1. Element not found. ```

[image]

```
public class TileBarButton {
    public TileBarButton() {

    }

    public TileBarButton Parent { get; }
    public ToolbarButtonType Type { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<TileBarButton> SubItems { get; }
}
```

What is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize the `PrimaryCommands` property in the ToolBarModule **Constructor** first.

Like this:

```
  public ToolBarModule()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        PrimaryCommands = new ObservableCollection<Button>();  
    }
```

Comment: I do initialise in the `ctor` with `this.PrimaryCommands = new ObservableCollection<TileBarButton>();` I should have included that code in my question sorry.

Comment: @Leigh That's interesting because when I initialize the DependencyProperty, the error won't exist.  What is the `TileBarButton`? I'm using the normal Button control to test. Have you tried with normal Button?

Comment: I've updated the question with the POCO of `TileBarButton`. My plan is to use this custom POCO to define properties of the controls to present on my UserControl.

Comment: @Leigh With the code of `TileBarButton`, it still works correctly after initializing the PrimaryCommands property in the ToolBarModule Constructor.

Comment: I did indeed try this with a `Button` with the same result. Still VS reports the same error and at runtime it doesn't work, the value of the property is not set.